# Cassandra-quarkus-client hangs at quarkusCqlSession.prepare

Tags: cassandra, quarkus

I spotted problem with Quarkus CqlSession. When i calling method "prepare" its hang and timeout.
Code snippet:

```
    @Inject
public NewsEngineRepository(QuarkusCqlSession quarkusCqlSession, NewsEngineConfig newsEngineConfig, Logger log) {
    queryLimit = newsEngineConfig.dbQueryLimit();
    this.quarkusCqlSession = quarkusCqlSession;
    this.log = log;
    SimpleStatement ss = SimpleStatement.newInstance("select " + ITEMID + ", " + PUBDATE + " from news_engine_items where defverid = ? AND group = ? Limit  " + queryLimit);

    preparedStatement= quarkusCqlSession.prepare(ss); // <---- hangs here

    this.log.info("Prepared statement created successfully: " + ss.getQuery());
}
```

I found a two solutions:

1. Increasing property quarkus.vertx.eventLoopsPoolSize from 2 to 4
2. Setting properyty quarkus.cassandra.use-quarkus-event-loop to false

Can anyone explain why solution 1 works?

Comment: When quarkus.cassandra.use-quarkus-event-loop is true (the default), the Cassandra driver uses Quarkus main event loop for *both* I/O and admin tasks. I can't tell for sure without analyzing a thread dump, but my feeling is that a pool of size 2 is way too small and is causing a deadlock. For comparison, the driver defaults are: 2 threads for admin tasks and processors*2 for I/O tasks. If you can provide a thread dump and a reproducer, please open an issue here: https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-quarkus/issues.

Comment: Actually I went ahead and did it: https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-quarkus/issues/194.